# Flutter Web not Scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created a basic website with graphs. I used a listview, a SingleChildScrollView and whenever I scroll, it zooms instead. It behaves like a mobile application that I have to click and drag to scroll.

Comment: Don't use Listview  and SingleChildScrollView both at same time

Comment: I tried them both separately.

Comment: add code to your ques. so we can help you out

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the command "flutter enable web". Maybe this is the reason for your web app behaves like mobile app. If not enabled web in your project then run that command.

Another scenario is;
Most of the flutter-web users facing the scrolling issue. But there is a temporary solution depends upon the number of items to be listed down. check out this youtube tutorial (https://youtu.be/qax_nOpgz7E), if the link is not working then search "lazy flutter performance" in youtube.

Reply back if this helps you to solve the issue or share that how did you resolved the issue.